# Possible safety problems with a low energy particle accelerator

Tags: particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, accelerator-physics

I am currently working on a low energy particle accelerator. Its main purpose would be to produce low energy  (few keV) electrons and metal ions for high precision non radioactive isotope selection. I've already dealt with the radiation of the accelerating charges and they are unlikely to produce a non negligible amount of harmful radiation. Besides these things the radiation will be monitored and the machine will be shut down if it is not working correctly.

Now that I made clean that I'm aware of what kind of security this machine needs I want to ask you: Do I need any precautions to start experimenting or do you have an advice? I just want to make sure that I don't do anything wrong. I'll post a simplified scheme of it if it's needed.

Comment: As it stands this is pretty unclear. Are we basically talking about pretty standard ion accelerator stuff (up to and including Calutrons)? Ions below ~100 kV are going to be pretty safe (barring accelerating deuterium in to tritium). Backstreaming of electrons may make some x-rays.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [safety of experiments](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1324/) are off-topic

Comment: When I asked the question I was thinking about phenomena that may occur during these  experiments and I haven't dealed with

Comment: Worry about exposed voltages (shock hazard), stored energy (capacitors etc), breach of vacuum vessels, things melting because your beam is focusing where you didn't expect it, the whole thing falling on your toe because of an earthquake ... assume that if anything can go wrong, it will - then ask yourself if you could detect, avert, alert, protect, shut down... We can't tell you "sure that sounds safe".

Comment: then sorry for the pointless question